# Event to add and remove a variable

Tags: c#, events

I have the following event which occurs when a new file is added

```
    public delegate void OnFileReceived(object sender, _File item);
    private OnFileReceived _fileReceivedHandler = null;
    public event OnFileReceived OnFileReceivedEvent
    {
        add { _fileReceivedHandler += value; }
        remove { _fileReceivedHandler -= value; }  //what does this line do?
    }

    public void AddFile(_File file)
    {
        RaiseFileEvents(file);
    }
```

In Application Constructor

```
public void Initialize()
{
    callback = new Callback();
    callback.OnFileReceivedEvent += Callback_OnFileReceivedEvent;
}
public void Callback_OnFileReceivedEvent(object sender, _File file)
{
    collection.Add(new _Item(file.Name,file.Path,file.Size));
}
```

My WCF service calls this event to add a file item in client's ListView, I would like to make the service be able to remove a file too, Do I have to make another event for that, or  Can I do it with the same event this way? :

```
callback.OnFileReceivedEvent -= Callback_OnFileRemovedEvent;
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> //what does this line do?

It unsubscribes given function from being executed when the event is fired. For me, this code looks suspicious. I would replace it by

```
public event EventHandler<_File> OnFileReceivedEvent;

public void AddFile(_File file)
{ 
    // ...
    // to raise event
    var handler = OnFileReceivedEvent;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, file);
}
```

> Do I have to make another event for that, or Can I do it with the same event this way?

You need to add another event for removing analogical to existing adding file.

I think you just need to read about events and everything will sort out ;)

Comment: And yes, the good practice is to pass a class derrived from EventArgs as parameter for EventHandler<>

Answer (score 0):

You have to make another event. You could roll it up into one event by creating a new class descending from EventArgs and creating an event with that as the second arg - it would contain the file name and the action; but that gets complicated and it not too clean (IMHO).

Incidentally, the remove line is to allow something to unsubscribe from it. It's generally easier to just do:

public event OnFileReceived OnFileReceivedEvent;

...and only put the add/remove if you want to control them yourself (which you won't very often).

Also, your event should really have it's second arg be a type derived from EventArgs: _File doesn't look like it does...

Cheers -

Comment: You mean it works the same if I replaced it with this line `public event OnFileReceived OnFileReceivedEvent;` ,The event is already working, but I don't know if I have written any unnecessary line out there, why does the event need its second arg?

Comment: Yep. If you don't provide the add and remove the the compiler will generate them for you along with the backing field (_fileReceivedHandler), just like it does with properties.

Comment: Not sure what second arg you're talking about: 'public event' is the accessibility (public) and what it is (an event). It's an event of type OnFileReceived (you'll have defined a delegate of that type) and you've called it OnFileReceivedEvent (could have been called Jim for all the compiler cares). That's all you need.